# How to initialize struct from 2 existed struct data in swift

Tags: swift, struct, codable

I have one public struct as following. I can create firstPeron and dupFirstPerson based on the way of init. However, is there anyway for me to create secondPerson struct with first, last property from firstPerson and with customized data for address and gender property? like the command out the code I have?

```
public struct Payload: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    public var lastName: String = ""
    public var firstName: String = ""
    public var number: String = ""
    public var address: String = ""
    public var gender: String = ""
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lastName = "LastName"
        case firstName = "FirstName"
        case number = "PhoneNumber"
        case address = "Address"
        case gender = "Gender"
    }
    }
    
    public init(first: String,
                last: String,
                number: String) {

        self.firstName = first
        self.lastName = last
        self.number = number
        Log.info("data: \(self)")
    }

    // any other way for me to do it?
    // public init(first: String,
    //             last: String,
    //             number: String,
    //             address: String,
    //             gender: String) {

    //     self.firstName = first
    //     self.lastName = last
    //     self.number = number
    //     self.address = address
    //     self.gender = gender
    //     Log.info("data: \(self)")
    // }


    public init(_ payload: Payload) {
        self = payload
    }
}

firstPerson = Payload(first: 'First', last: 'Person', number: 1)
dupFirstPerson = Payload(firstPerson)
secondPerson = Payload(firstPerson) // I would like to create secondPerson struct with first, last property from firstPerson and with customized data for address and gender property
// secondPerson = Payload(first: firstPeron.firstName
                          last: firstPeron.lastName
                          number: firstPeron.number
                          address: "set address",
                          gender: "set gender") // I would like to create secondPerson struct with first, last property from firstPerson and with customized data for address and gender property
```

Comment: Just copy `firstPerson` and set the properties you want? `secondPerson.address = "set address"` and `secondPerson.gender = "set gender"`.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Be aware that the syntax `dupFirstPerson = firstPerson` creates a copy of `firstPerson`. No need to call the initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
public struct Payload: Codable {
    public var lastName: String
    public var firstName: String
    public var number: String
    public var address: String = ""
    public var gender: String = ""

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lastName = "LastName"
        case firstName = "FirstName"
        case number = "PhoneNumber"
        case address = "Address"
        case gender = "Gender"
    }

    public init(
        first: String,
        last: String,
        number: String
    ) {
        self.firstName = first
        self.lastName = last
        self.number = number
    }

     public init(
        _ payload: Payload,
        address: String = "",
        gender: String = ""
     ) {
         self.firstName = payload.firstName
         self.lastName = payload.lastName
         self.number = payload.number
         self.address = address
         self.gender = gender
     }
}

let firstPerson = Payload(first: "First", last: "Person", number: "1")
let dupFirstPerson = Payload(firstPerson)
let secondPerson = Payload(firstPerson, address: "set address", gender: "set gender")
```

In the second initializer we can take the firstName and lastName from the other payload and use then the new data for address and gender